# How to render errors / warnings directly inside editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for setting / extension, which enable to render errors / warnings inside editor viewlet instead of hover and red underscore.

[image: Desired behaviour]

[image: Actual behaviour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens

which is a fork of this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilHindle.errorlens

[image: demo]